# How to adjust the length of Discussion Text Box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, discussion-board

A simple question but i was not able to change the text box and it keeps cutting off words i have copied and pasted- as can be seen below with the line

I have check properties but not having success in editing the Community Discussion List

I was told this has not to do anything with the column properties, rather I need to check out my css in the view page. Some css is meddling with the width of the div that holds the body text.

However i have no inkling how to do this as i am not a dev. Anyone could point me to the right direction?

[image]

Comment: If you are using custom CSS then you can set a property to the Div tag as .divex {
    overflow: scroll;
}

Answer (score 0):

Please override .ms-rtestate-field CSS class like this:

```
.ms-rtestate-field {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 800px;!important
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will increase the textbox length:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry thank you very much for the reply - however could you advice how to overide the CSS? I tried Content editor and add to the Discussion List the below but it doesnt work 

I tried using F12 but of course the changes are not saved, any advice how to edit the source? Do i use something like Sharepoint Editor? I dont even know where to begin with this but I am still learning

Comment: Perhaps I should use Scrip Editor or Custom Css..not sure but i could explore? Just not sure which direction to head

Comment: Please add the code in Script Editor Web Part in the page.